# I have a line chart that I want to use to show temperature, but I want to show icons and time in x axis

Tags: android, kotlin, linechart, mpandroidchart

what I want to achieve
[image]

what I have[image]

I want to show icons on the xAxis above time but line chart takes icon and places them on the value where temperature is shown. I have searched a lot but could not find the answer. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried a lot of things but all in vein.

```
    private fun setTempChart(hour: ArrayList<Hour>, id: String) {
        val entries: MutableList<Entry> = ArrayList()
        for (i in hour.indices) {
            val code = hour[i].condition.code
            val icon =
                if (hour[i].is_day == 1) requireActivity().setIconDay(code) else requireActivity().setIconNight(
                    code
                )
            entries.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), sharedPreference.temp?.let {
                hour[i].temp_c.setCurrentTemperature(
                    it
                ).toFloat()
            }!!))
        }
        val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "")
        dataSet.apply {
            lineWidth = 0f
            setDrawCircles(false)
            setDrawCircleHole(false)
            isHighlightEnabled = false
            valueTextColor = Color.WHITE
            setColors(Color.WHITE)
            valueTextSize = 12f
            mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
            setDrawFilled(true)
            fillColor = Color.WHITE
            valueTypeface = typeface
            isDrawIconsEnabled
            setDrawIcons(true)
            valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
                override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                    return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f", value)
                }
            }
        }
        val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
        chart.apply {
            description.isEnabled = false
            axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
            axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
            legend.isEnabled = false
            axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
            axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
            axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false)
            axisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)
            setScaleEnabled(false)
            data = lineData
            setVisibleXRange(8f, 8f)
            animateY(1000)
            xAxis.apply {
                setDrawAxisLine(false)
                textColor = Color.WHITE
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                setDrawLabels(true)
                position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                textSize = 12f
                valueFormatter = MyAxisFormatter(hour, id)
                isGranularityEnabled = true
                granularity = 1f
                labelCount = entries.size
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using MPAndroidChart library

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a nice built-in way to draw icons like that, but you can do it by making a custom extension of the [LineChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java) and overriding `drawExtras`. Then you can get your icons from `R.drawable.X` and draw them on the canvas wherever you want. There is some work to figure out where to put them to line up with the data points, but you can copy the logic from `drawCircles` to find that.

**Example Custom Renderer**

```kotlin
inner class MyRenderer(private val context: Context, 
                       private val iconY: Float,
                       private val iconSizeDp: Float,
                       chart: LineDataProvider, 
                       animator: ChartAnimator, 
                       viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler)
    : LineChartRenderer(chart, animator, viewPortHandler) {

    private var buffer: FloatArray = listOf(0f,0f).toFloatArray()

    override fun drawExtras(c: Canvas) {
        super.drawExtras(c)

        val iconSizePx = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            iconSizeDp,
            resources.displayMetrics
        )

        // get the icons you want to draw
        val cloudy = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cloudy)
        val sunny = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.sunny)

        if( cloudy == null || sunny == null ) {
            throw RuntimeException("Missing drawables")
        }
        
        // Determine icon width in pixels
        val w = iconSizePx 
        val h = iconSizePx 

        val dataSets = mChart.lineData.dataSets
        val phaseY = mAnimator.phaseY

        for(dataSet in dataSets) {
            mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet)
            val boundsRange = mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min
            val transformer = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.axisDependency)

            for(j in mXBounds.min .. boundsRange) {
                val e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j) ?: break

                buffer[0] = e.x
                buffer[1] = iconY * phaseY

                transformer.pointValuesToPixel(buffer)

                if( !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer[0])) {
                    break
                }

                if( !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer[0]) || 
                    !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(buffer[1])) {
                    continue
                }

                // Draw the icon centered under the data point, but at a fixed
                // vertical position. Here the icon "sits on top" of the
                // specified iconY value
                val left = (buffer[0]-w/2).roundToInt()
                val right = (buffer[0]+w/2).roundToInt()
                val top = (buffer[1]-h).roundToInt()
                val bottom = (buffer[1]).roundToInt()

                // Alternately, use this to center the icon at the
                // "iconY" value  
                //val top = (buffer[1]-h/2).roundToInt()
                //val bottom = (buffer[1]+h/2).roundToInt()

                // Use whatever logic you want to select which icon
                // to use at each position
                val icon = if( e.y > 68f ) {
                    sunny
                }
                else {
                    cloudy
                }

                icon.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
                icon.draw(c)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Using the Custom Renderer**

```kotlin
val iconY = 41f
val iconSizeDp = 40f
chart.renderer = MyRenderer(this, iconY, iconSizeDp, 
                            chart, chart.animator, chart.viewPortHandler)
```

(other formatting)

```kotlin
val chart = findViewById<LineChart>(R.id.chart)

chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
val yAx = chart.axisLeft
yAx.setDrawLabels(false)
yAx.setDrawGridLines(false)
yAx.setDrawAxisLine(false)
yAx.axisMinimum = 40f
yAx.axisMaximum = 80f

val xAx = chart.xAxis
xAx.setDrawLabels(false)
xAx.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
xAx.setDrawGridLines(false)
xAx.setDrawAxisLine(false)
xAx.axisMinimum = 0.5f
xAx.axisMaximum = 5.5f
xAx.granularity = 0.5f

val x = listOf(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
val y = listOf(60,65,66,70,65,50,55)
val e = x.zip(y).map { Entry(it.first.toFloat(), it.second.toFloat())}
val line = LineDataSet(e, "temp")
line.setDrawValues(true)
line.setDrawCircles(false)
line.circleRadius = 20f // makes the text offset up
line.valueTextSize = 20f
line.color = Color.BLACK
line.lineWidth = 2f
line.setDrawFilled(true)
line.fillColor = Color.BLACK
line.fillAlpha = 50
line.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
line.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
        return "%.0f F".format(value)
    }
}

chart.data = LineData(line)
chart.description.isEnabled = false
chart.legend.isEnabled = false
```

Gives the desired effect

[image: chart]

Comment: its not showing any icons

Comment: Did you try adjusting the hard-coded 650 pixel value? It was probably drawing them outside the boundary of your chart. I updated the answer to draw the icons at a fixed Y value in chart units instead of pixels, and to use an icon size in dp instead of pixels (should work better across devices). You will have to adjust the `iconY` position to set where they are drawn still though. Make sure you pick a value that is within your y axis bounds.

Comment: Also, make sure the drawables referenced in there (e.g. `R.drawable.cloudy`) exist, or it will return without drawing anything... You should change those to refer to whatever icons you want to draw.